# How can I update a question (from someone else) with keywords so you can find it better?

Tags: discussion, edits, questions, search

I sometimes have the problem that I cannot find an existing answer in Stack Exchange. So I would really like to "improve" a question by adding keywords to make it easier to find.

Is there such a possibility? I think tags are not suitable for this...right?

Comment: This very question gives a good example. It started with wrong tags (both tags were wrong, this isn't a feature request, and it's not about the search engine), and now edited to have correct tags. This way it's now much easier to find it in the future. This is a [tag:discussion] about [tag:edits] made to [tag:questions] in order to improve [tag:search].

Comment: thank you for your very kindness. Your comment makes this site a much better place....

Comment: Well I'd say "Thanks for editing my question and putting the correct tags", but each and their own attitude, all good. Now to be more serious, my edit was really just to make the question better, and it's really being example for exactly what is being asked here. I was never trying to be kind or unkind.

Comment: so was my question meant - i wanted to improve SE so that something can be found. But yeah - i don't keep all rules - this was one of my first posts here - and i got a warm welcome with -8 reputation - that's why i LOVE SE. The people are so kind and understanding... no wonder that more and more people leave that site...and no, i don't read and search all tags possible before i post a question and i don't read all rules here before i post - and i would bet - most of the people don't do that...but i will enjoy more downvotes... ;) and yes, that's my last comment here...

Comment: ...because discussing on this site makes no sense to me, don't take it personally...but it's a waste of time for me ;)

Comment: The downvotes are because people don't think we should add keywords to questions, because we can add or change the tags, as the answer also says. And I'll try again to explain, that's exactly what I did here. Nobody is expecting you to know all tags and you broke no rules here.

Comment: thanks for that information

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags are exactly the thing here, assuming they are the right ones for the question. Although if the question needs an edit to fix any grammar or spelling issues, be sure to do that too, just don't change it so radically it no longer looks like the original poster's question.

Note that creating a new tag won't make a question more discoverable because it will be the only question with that tag.

In any case what you're actually trying to do is add a tag that's already a synonym of an existing tag i.e. [formula is a synonym of mathematics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/mathematics/synonyms) and the question already has that tag. That's the real reason you can't add that particular tag to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. the problem is just i cannot create tags in Blender exchange... :( also my reputation is high enough there...

Comment: @Chris on that site creating tags require [300 reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) so you should have it. What happens when you try to add a tag that does not exist yet to a question? Do you get error?

Comment: unfortunately it happens...nothing...like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/937r4.gif

Comment: Ok, thank you for that explanation. Although (just my personal opinion) I think that mathematics is no synonym for formula.

Comment: @Chris you'd have to take that up on [Blender's Meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It’s ok for me. I have an explanation, but I don’t want to make it „bigger“ than now. I am sorry, but that’s waste of time for me. I had already discussions here…(a lot) and obviously I am not someone who can hold rules which (in my opinion) make no sense and so it will end up the same (I mean this discussion) as usual…but really thank you for your answer and explanation! I appreciate that. And obviously I think in a different way than most people here.